# Pass parameter from MVC view to an action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass a parameter from a view to an action through the following jQuery code, but I don't succeed to pass the parameter. Am I missing something?

```
$('li').click(function () {  
employeeID = $(this).attr('id');    
window.location.href = '/ApproveWork/GetEmployeeDays/'+employeeID; 
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDays(string userCode)
{
     .....
    return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);
}
```

routing from Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );          
  }
```

P.S. I tried to use AJAX jQuery function, but this doesn't return me the view that I specified in the Action.

Comment: Where is `parameter_to_pass` defined and what is it's value? Also, seeing your action method may help.

Comment: @pisi Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @pisi Can you post your routing code?

Answer (score 9):

Is your javascript on the view page

If so use the Url.Action helper to build the url in the normal way

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {parametername = "REPLACEME"})';
window.location.href = url.Replace('REPLACEME', parameter_value);
```

**Updated to account for client side variable**
**Update 2: updated typo**

Comment: If `parameter_value` is a javascript variable (as it would appear to be in the OP) this won't work.

Comment: Thanks! This parameter is a javascript value. I have to arange a little the code that @NinjaNye indicated; it gave me some syntax errror

Comment: Thanks @NinjaNye! I have a problem with this "parametername"; I think that isn't recognized by javascript; it's underlined with red, and i try to find why.

Comment: parameter name is simply the name of the query string parameter you want to assign your value.  OH, I missed a bracket after the last }... that might be your issue

Comment: I've updated my answer to correct the typo's.. Apologies, this was answered from memory.  Please try again....

Comment: Thanks again for your promptitude. This is my new code: ` var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork", new {parametername: "userCode"})';
            window.location.href = url.Replace('userCode', employeeID);' and I still have sintax error on `parametername`

Comment: Change to var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork", new {parametername = "userCode"}). That should fix it

Comment: Thanks. I solved that error syntax, but I don't get in the action. that's look ok in firefox debugger; ` var url = '/ApproveWork/GetEmployeeDays?parametername=userCode';`. I will try more. thank you verry much

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with ajax?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork")',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: { userCode: $(this).attr('id') }
 })
```

Comment: Nice, could you streamline further using $.get

Comment: thanks a lot! I made some debugging and  the ajax method calls the controller action, pass the parameter, render the right view ( that I indicated in the return), but finally it loads the same view from I made the request. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @Pabloker, Can you help me to find why It doesn't return the desired view-> GetEmployeeDays? I search over the Internet, but no optimal result

Comment: What do you mean with: _render the right view ( that I indicated in the return), but finally it loads the same view from I made the request_? Render the view or not?

Comment: I used debugger and I saw that, after the method is called, all the instructions are executed. At the `return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);`, the "GetEmployeeDays" view receives the values from model and is populated, but finally in the browser I receive the initial view (from I made the request)- not the `GetEmployeeDays`.

Comment: You could use ajax if you want to see the details in a partial view. But if you have a table with employees and want to see a "detail" view you could use ActionLink instead.

Comment: This worked for me, I was trying to build an instant search and this plus the "success:" ajax setting did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check your Global.asax file the register routes?

Please check the optional variable name over there.

Suppose you have register route using following.

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

You have to write your action below way.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDays(int id)
{
     .....
    return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);
}
```

or

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDays(string id)
{
     .....
    return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass parameter with the help of `@Url.Action` with jquery.
You can create initial string containing url and then you can pass that string to `window.location.href`

```
$_BaseUrl="Your application url";

<script>
 Window.location.href = $_BaseUrl + '/Admin/Account/SwitchSuperAdminLogin?UserName=' + user + '&Password=' + pass + '&IndustryId=' + indus;
 </script>
```